# Why does fail the second iteration of a test collection on POSTMAN?

Tags: javascript, postman

So I've a huge collection of tests on Postman and in the first execution all works perfectly normal, but, when I try to run it again for the second, third or how many times I want, It always fails in the same two tests:

[image]

What It is behind all those checks is a simple HTTP CRUD interaction with my localhost server.

I have this array of elements in my initialData.js:

```js
var air_routesData = [
    {
        "district" : "Madrid",
        "year": 2020,
        "flight": 158405,
        "passenger": 17071089,
        "merchandise": 401133380
    
    },{
        "district" : "Cataluña",
        "year": 2017,
        "flight": 320456,
        "passenger": 47262688,
        "merchandise": 156105304
    },{
        "district": "Andalucía",
        "year": 2020,
        "flight": 78777,
        "passenger": 7441585,
        "merchandise": 10561907
    },{
        "district": "Andalucía",
        "year": 2019,
        "flight": 194370,
        "passenger": 27332163,
        "merchandise": 12971632
    },{
        "district": "Madrid",
        "year": 2019,
        "flight": 417958,
        "passenger": 61703370,
        "merchandise": 558566726
    }
];

module.exports.JsonInitialData = air_routesData;
```

My project has more files to play with this (GET/POST/DELETE/PUT with the root path and per each resource) but I'm not sure if I can post that long ass file (almost 180 lines).

The first "Initial Check" only does a simple GET to localhost:1607/api/v1/air_routes and returns nothing more than an empty array.
The second "loadInitialData" loads the above mentioned array with a GET and with "Check Array 5 tam" it checks that the array lenght is the same as the loaded (5).
Postman gives me this error:
[image]

I've done some DELETE's so the next time it iterates, it would be empty, but for some reason it doesn't work, and keeps loading the old resources I pushed with POST.

Comment: without adding information like what is there in your request how would someone help. The only thing that could be suggested is to check whether the requests are saved (no orange dot indication) before running collection runner

Comment: @PDHide what do you mean by "whether the requests are saved (no orange dot indication)"? I use a local array initiated with all the initialData and then, this array is used and modified by each method (post, get, delete, etc).

Comment: make sure that single request is saved , please add more information or share your collection

Comment: if you are using single request how are you modifying the request name ?